# How to use and import eSpeak in eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, text-to-speech, espeak

I am newbie in android dev.

How can i import eSpeak to my android project and use it to read texts?

Where can i download the eSpeak library?

I just found :

http://espeak.sourceforge.net/

https://github.com/rhdunn/espeak#android

But Where is the android project and How to use it?

Is there any sample code to read text?

Thanks.

Comment: @DerGolem I have to use it. Because i want to convert Persian text into sound. Please help.

Comment: I know nothing of eSpeak. I know nothing of C++. I know nothing of Persian. How could I help you?

Comment: Nothing to be sorry. You could try to find some other TTS Engine with Persian language support.

Answer (score 5):

just go through these links,

[add my TTS Engine to Android TTS Serivce like SAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560549/add-my-tts-engine-to-android-tts-serivce-like-sapi)

http://eyes-free.googlecode.com/svn@795/trunk/documentation/tutorial/tutorial.html

Hope this will help you..

Comment: is it possible to include the espeak project into in my project and use it in my own application? I need something that get installed with my settings with my app. is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for the android branch of this project?

https://github.com/rhdunn/espeak/tree/android

and how to build it

https://github.com/rhdunn/espeak/tree/android#building

You could also try installing one of these two apps and use them from your app.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.eyesfree.espeak
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.reecedunn.espeak - Paid

Here is a thread discussing how to set language while using the first option.
 - [using eSpeak tts engine in application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431858/using-espeak-tts-engine-in-application)

TTS is a low level feature. May be better to keep it standalone. You can always install an apk as part of your app install. Please see the thread [Can an Android app install another android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095726/can-an-android-app-install-another-android-app)

From your app invoke the required TTS engine.

Hope it helps.

Comment: is it possible to include the espeak project into in my project and use it in my own application? I need something that get installed with my settings with my app. is this possible?